# Plotting data of predicted values

Tags: r, plot, intervals, mcmc

I estimate a binary choice model for doctor visits regarding the factors age in years and sex (using MCMC). In the next step, I want to create **predicted values graphs** for both males and females with **x=age** (I choose an interval form 25 to 60 years), and **y=predicted values** with R. I want to show **99% credible intervals**.

The plot should look like this:

[image]

I already defined the data for this plot. You see that I defined interval for age and the 99% credible intervals:

[image]

I used the R code to define the data:

```
datamen <- data.frame(age = seq(25,60,1), female = 0) #interval for women
datawomen <- data.frame (age = seq(25,60,1), female = 1) #interval for men
newdata <-rbind(datamen, datawomen) 
p_preds <- posterior_linpred (m1, newdata=newdata, transform=TRUE) #m1 is the data of my logit model
p_pred <- apply(p_preds, 2, mean)
p_pred_lb <- apply (p_preds, 2, quantile, probs=0.005) #credible interval lower end
p_pred_ub <- apply (p_preds, 2, quantile, probs=0.995) #credible interval upper end
newdata <- cbind(newdata, p_pred, p_pred_lb, p_pred_ub) #new data is the data shown above
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newdata %>% 
  mutate(female = factor(female, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Male", "Female"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=age)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = p_pred_lb, ymax = p_pred_ub, group=female), alpha=.25) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=p_pred, linetype=female)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=p_pred, group=female)) + 
  labs(x="Age", y="Predicted Probability (99% Credible Intervals)", 
       linetype="") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```